# Why can't I file my California LLC Statement of Information online

Tags: limited-liability-company, california

I am trying to file my required statement of Information using the form at https://businessfilings.sos.ca.gov. The site fails to find my Limited Liability Company by name. I have gone through all my documents and have failed to find a 7 digit corporate number. The ftb faq is useless, [this](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/online/access_your_account/faq.shtml#b1) is the best I could find.

Perhaps the number is obfuscated inside of the 15 digit sos number?

Any help is appreciated and will probably prevent me from accruing some unjustified fine.

P.S why do i have to pay $20 to notify California that nothing has changed? In my world no news is good news. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "California SOS file number" and where do I find it?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/what-is-the-california-sos-file-number-and-where-do-i-find-it)

Comment: sos number is 15 digits, corporate number is 7. https://www.ftb.ca.gov/online/access_your_account/faq.shtml#b1

Comment: SOS number is not 15 digits. The entity number is assigned by the SOS. Corp numbers usually start with C, LLC usually start with the year of incorporation.

Comment: okay now we are getting somewhere, so remove the year and I am left with an 11 digit number.

Comment: No, you don't remove the year. Year is part of the number. Are you talking about Limited Liability Company (LLC) or a corporation? What did you have registered?

Comment: You said "limited liability corporation" - there's no such thing. There is "limited liability company". What did you register as?

Comment: Yes this is a Limited Liability Company

Comment: Then why are you looking for corporate number? You're registered as LLC, you don't have corporate number.

Comment: Okay got it. An LLC does not have a corporate number. The web site is not finding the llc by name, I assumed I needed to lookup by the other available option corporate number.

Comment: Make sure you use the right forms: http://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/forms/#llc The one you linked to is for a corporation, not LLC. Also, when you search by name you need to select "limited liability company/partnership name", not corporation.

Comment: Thank you litteadv. I was looking at the incorrect form. Frustrating that the https://businessfilings.sos.ca.gov website is not finding my llc.

Comment: Again, it doesn't because you're in the corp site. Search here: http://kepler.sos.ca.gov/ Pay attention to where you are.

Comment: I should probably delete this post as it probably not helpful to anyone else and a complete show of my ignorance :)

Comment: yes it works at kepler.sos.ca.gov but I need to file a statement of information. I guess only corporations can file online?

Comment: Well, maybe if you rephrase it to reflect the actual problem it will be helpful to others who are as confused. You'd be surprised, but it is really not that intuitive.

Comment: Yes, only corporations can file online. You need to fill, print, mail with a check.

Comment: "P.S why do i have to pay $20 to notify California that nothing has changed? In my world no news is good news. :)" You have to do this because the State of California is betting that some LLCs will forget and will then be charged a $250 fine.

Answer (score 3):

Filing the required Statement of Information for Limited Liability Companies online is not supported.

The postcard reminder reads:

> Most corporations can file online at https://businessfilings.sos.ca.gov/.

IMO it should read:

> All Limited Liability Companies must file by mail. Most corporations can file online at https://businessfilings.sos.ca.gov/

Also note the first page of the Form LLC-12R should be ignored because it states:

> The fastest way for a corporation to file their required Statement of Information is to file online using our online E-File Statements of Information for Corporations at https://businessfilings.sos.ca.gov/ and request a copy over the counter in our Sacramento office, if a copy or certified copy is needed.

There is a helpful tool for gathering information at http://kepler.sos.ca.gov/.